# Deploy a Laravel App on AWS EB - inconsistent Sessions

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, session, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-5.5

I try to Deploy a Laravel App via AWS ElasticBeanstalk with Classic Load Balancer.

I store my laravel sessions in a database on an AWS RDS, the connection is working fine.

It is all working fine, except that every request is generating a new session.

In my .ebextensions I added therefore, session stickiness

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    SSLCertificateId: my_ssl_arn...
    InstancePort: 80
    InstanceProtocol: HTTP
  aws:elb:listener:80:
    ListenerEnabled: true
  aws:elb:policies:sessionstickiness:
    CookieName: laravel_session
    LoadBalancerPorts: 443, 80
```

In the App itself, i force via middleware to use https://

Its Laravel Version 5.5, in the TrustProxiesMiddleware i added:

```
protected $proxies = '**';
```

I just don't understand where the problem is and tried already a lot of different settings.

Did anyone get experience with that? What do I oversee here?

Comment: Did you try fideloper/proxy  package? It automatically adds X_FORWARDED headers to request.

Comment: Yes this one is included in the laravel framework.

Comment: Can you verify X_FORWARDED headers exists; using dd($request)

Comment: var_dump($request->header()); has -> ["x-forwarded-for"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "MY_IP" } ["x-forwarded-port"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "443" } ["x-forwarded-proto"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "https" }

Comment: The mistake was in a completely different place, then I thought. The mistake was in not changing the session domain from my local .dev domain to the new .com domain correctly. But thanks for your help.

Comment: you are   welcome